# Points Matching in 3D

Tags: algorithms

Let A and B be two sets of unordered 3D points. Set B is obtained by applying the same transformation to every point in set A. How do I match points from A to points of B? Is there a standard algorithm?

To make things worse, the actual sets might have slightly different sizes, and the positions might be slightly shifted.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What kind of transformation? Or do you think of the transformation as an unknown operation, and the problem is to find this operation?

Comment: For a rigid transformation, the "standard" algorithm is known as Iterated Closest Points.

Comment: @DocBrown Translation + Rotation + Scaling (less likely). The points are acquired by a device. The operator is free to add them in a random order and the object might be rotated. The points have additional properties which must match the associated points of the model.

Comment: @CFlat: so you are talking about *affine* transformations (to be precise: angle preserving affine transformations), right? Still not sure what your question is: do you mean how to find some transformation parameters for a transformation T so the points T(A) approximate B by some distance metrics (like least-squares sum)? And what precisely do you mean by "additional properties which must match the associated points"? I recommend you edit the question and give an example.

Comment: @DocBrown I do not know how to formalize the problem - I'm far away from my comfort zone. Imagine that the points have a `name` property. And there is no transformation and no acquisition error - only the acquisition order differs. And you are asked to copy the names from set A to corresponding points in B. In 1D you would sort both sets and then copy the names from A to B. I guess _Point-set registration_ is close to what I need.

Comment: @CFlat: when you have issues to formalize the problem, add a detailed example. That's why I told you to use the "edit" button; here in the comment section, a useful example won't fit and will less likely be found by other readers. Currently, I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. Try to tell us precisely what is the *input* to your problem, and what exactly is the kind of *output* you expect.

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments. Instead, [edit] the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time and has all the information needed to understand what is being asked, without someone having to read the comments to understand what is being asked.  Then, flag the comments as 'no longer needed'.  Comments exist to help you improve your question, not for general discussion.

Comment: It might help to do some research on point set registration / image registration (here and elsewhere), then add to your question an explanation of why you have rejected those methods and what additional requirements you have or how your problem is similar/different.